# Fourier transform of the projection operator in 3D

Tags: vector-analysis, distribution-theory, fourier-transform

I have a vector field $A_i({\bf r})$, a Fourier transform given by

$$ \tilde A_i({\bf k}) = \int d^3 r~e^{i {\bf r.k}}A_i({\bf r}),$$

and projections given by $\mathcal P_{ij}(\hat r) 
= \delta_{ij} - \hat r_i \hat r_j$, that acts on $A_i({\bf r})$, giving

$$[\mathcal P.{\bf A}]_i({\bf r}) = A_i({\bf r}) 
- [\hat r_j A_j({\bf r})]\hat r_i.$$

I'm interested in computing the Fourier transform of the projection, i.e.  $\widetilde{ [\mathcal P.{\bf A}]}_i({\bf k})$. I tried obtaining the explicit formula 
for $\tilde{\mathcal P}_{ij}({\bf k})$ so that I could use convolution

$$
\widetilde{[\mathcal P.{\bf A}]}_i({\bf k}) = \int \frac{d^3 p}{(2\pi)^3}~ \tilde{\mathcal P}_{ij}({\bf p - k}) \tilde A_i({\bf k}).
~~~~~~~~~~~~(1)
$$

I got

$$\tilde{\mathcal P}_{ij}({\bf k}) = \int d^3 r ~ \mathcal P_{ij}({\bf r}) e^{i {\bf r.k}} = (2\pi)^3 \delta_{ij} \delta^D({\bf k}) 
- \int d^3 r ~ (\hat r_i \hat r_j) e^{i {\bf r.k}},$$

but I don't quite know how to represent the last integral as some useful distribution that I would know how to apply in the convolution formula above (similar to the delta function part). I know I can formally represent it as

$$\int d^3 r ~ (\hat r_i \hat r_j) e^{i {\bf r.k}} = (2\pi)^3 \frac{\partial_{k_i}\partial_{k_j}}{\partial^2_{k}}\delta^D({\bf k}),$$

but this does not help me much when I try to apply it in the convolution (1) above for some specific field $A_i({\bf k})$. 
Is there some useful way I can represent $\tilde{\mathcal P}_{ij}({\bf k})$ that will be practical for computing the convolution (1) above?